# Accessing timezone data from twitter using python

Tags: python, twitter

I'm working on a project where I collected a 2 days of tweets using the Twitter API and read it into a text file. I now would like to look at the time zones where those tweets were from. The text file seems to have a key with time_zone, here's a snippet:

```
"created_at":"Mon Oct 29 22:37:25 +0000 2012","utc_offset":10800,"time_zone":"Baghdad"
```

But when I try to get the timezone information, I get an error saying that says KeyError: 'time_zone'. This is the code I'm using:

```
tweets_data = []
tweets_file = open(tweets_data_path, "r")
for line in tweets_file:
    try:
        tweet = json.loads(line)
        tweets_data.append(tweet)
    except:
        continue

tweets = pd.DataFrame()

tweets['timezone'] = list(map(lambda tweet: (tweet['time_zone'] if 'time_zone' != None else None ),tweets_data))
```

Thanks!

Comment: So you have a tweet that doesn't have a `time_zone` key in it... What do you want to do with that?

Comment: I actually just figured out the problem. 'time_zone' is nested in the 'user' key.

Comment: `pandas` also has tools for loading json data... you might want to check those out...